# Change name of winform components of C# in code with visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

When I create a win-form project and add some components to the form by drag them from the tool box, everything works nice, binding codes are generated but components' names are given by default, like button1, button2... I think they are not appropriate for code maintenance.

So I want to name them like button_add, button_del and some name like that, more meaningful, so I change the name in the attribute box of the component, but I don't see any change in the code.

Can some one show me how to do this?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: Why this not a programming question?

Comment: It technically does not address a programming problem, but a problem with using the development environment - which has been topic of many questions, which is why I vote to leave the question open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually such changes should be performed automatically by Visual Studio when you change the control's name. **The only thing not being renamed are event handlers**.

For example: If you add a `Click` handler to a button named `button1` the method will be named `button1_Click` by Visual Studio. The method name will *not* change if you rename the button to `button_add`. This is probably because you can name the method yourself, for example `ItWasPressed` - how should Visual Studio handle this? If it renamed the method, you'd complain that Visual Studio turned your nicely named method into `button_add_Click` automatically :-)

You can simplify this refactoring-step by modifying the method name, then pressing `Shift+Alt+F10` and selecting the respective option to rename all occurrances.

However, all other references in code will be changed, like for example `button1.Enabled = false;` will be changed to `button_add.Enabled = false;`.

Comment: Yes, it's really confusing me, as a newbie that visual studio did't do the job automatically properly. after I change the text of the component, I check the code out, and the method didn't change.

Comment: It never does. Even though the default method name contains the name of the component, it is not necessary to name the method like that. You could also name the method `MyButtonWasClicked`. How should Visual Studio handle that case? The fact that all other references are renamed is because for every control on the form there's also a variable in code. There would be inconsistencies if the names were different.

Comment: Thanks, So the only way I can do this is [drag a component] -> [rename its text attribute in view] -> [rename the method in control method] -> [reflect the binding code] ? right? Is there any way that I can decide the component's name after dragging the component into form, but before the auto-generated name was created. So that both I and the IDE could save some energy?

Comment: Usually you add a control to the form, change its name and then attach the events. If you need to rename the control later - after attaching events - you can decide whether you need to rename the methods as well. You could also go ahead and (after renaming the control) do a search/replace over all files and change `oldname_` to `newname_`. Otherwise I don't know of any other way and seriously, I've never spent too much thought on it...